# Django BooleanField - Checkbox not showing in form on website

Tags: django, django-forms

I have the following:

forms.py

```
class StoreSettingsForm(ModelForm):
    enable_repricer = forms.BooleanField(required=True)
    enable_ignore_min_price = forms.BooleanField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Store
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['user']
```

models.py

```
    class Store(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
        store_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
        ...
        enable_repricer = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        enable_ignore_min_price = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

template.html

```
<form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}    
<h4>Repricer Settings</h4>
                <div class="row">
                       {{ form.non_field_errors }}
                    <div class="fieldWrapper col s4">
                        {{ form.enable_repricer.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.enable_repricer.id_for_label }}">Enable Repricer:</label>
                        {{ form.enable_repricer }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldWrapper col s4">
                        {{ form.enable_ignore_min_price.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.enable_ignore_min_price.id_for_label }}">Allow Repricer to ignore min_price:</label>
                        {{ form.enable_ignore_min_price }}
                    </div>
                    <div class="fieldWrapper col s4">
                        {{ form.repricer_factor.errors }}
                        <label for="{{ form.repricer_factor.id_for_label }}">Repricer aggressiveness factor (1-100):</label>
                        {{ form.repricer_factor }}
                    </div>
                </div>
<input class="btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
```

view.py

```
class StoreSettingsView(View):
    template_name = 'store_settings.html'

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        store = Store.objects.get(id=kwargs['id'])
        data = {
            'store_name': store.store_name,
            'store_email': store.store_email,
            ...
            'enable_ignore_min_price': store.enable_ignore_min_price,
            'enable_repricer': store.enable_repricer,
            'repricer_factor': store.repricer_factor,
        }
        form = StoreSettingsForm(initial=data)

        return render(self.request, self.template_name, {
            "store": store,
            "form": form,
        })
```

It does not show up in the form. All field are showing on the page but not the 2 boolean fields. The labels are showing and in the HTML.

I have excluded many fields from the code blocks to make it more easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. When typing the question something arose to me. What if.... and yes that was it. In some way my CSS is disabling the checkbox and i really do not know why. When removing the CSS it works fine. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I was with this problem and I solved it doing that:

#----- My error was caused by Materialize css ----#

Not showing checkbox

```
<form>
  {% for field in form %}
     {{field.label_tag}}<br>
     {{field}}
     <br>
     <br>
   {% endfor %}

</form>
```

Using Materialize, You must have a span tag in your label:

Example in Materialize doc:

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" checked="checked" />
   <span>Filled in</span>
</label>
```

I solved the problem refacting to the Materialize's doc structure:

```
<form>
        {% for field in form %}
        <label>
            {% if field.label == "colorida" %} <!-- 'colorida' is my boolean field -->
                {{field}}
                <span>{{field.label}}</span> <!-- if boolean field, span must be after input (in materialize) -->
            {% else %}
                <span>{{field.label}}</span> <!-- description before input if not boolean field -->
                {{field}}
            {% endif %}
        </label>
        <br>
        <br>
        {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

Test your example on a page without any CSS, the problem probably is caused by CSS